# UIVIew size use device size in interface builder and no constraint

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, interface-builder

I have the following scene in interface builder.

[image]

and the following code in the viewDidLoad function of the controller

```
print(String.init(format:"baseCircleView width %f height %f", baseCircleView.bounds.size.width, baseCircleView.bounds.size.height))
print(String.init(format:"userDrawingView width %f height %f", userDrawingView.bounds.size.width, userDrawingView.bounds.size.height))
print(String.init(format:"View width %f height %f", self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
```

When i launch the app (on the iPhone6 simulator but with "View as : iPhone SE" selected in the storyboard), i have the following in the console :

> baseCircleView width 320.000000 height 504.000000
>
> userDrawingView width 320.000000 height 504.000000
>
> View width 375.000000 height 667.000000

I do not understand why my 2 views infer their sizes from the device "View as : iPhone SE" selected in the storyboard and not their superview.

Can somebody help me figure what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test your constraints at viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Here is a blog post for additional info about UIViewController lifecycle:
https://blog.caramba.io/ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle-261e3e2f6133

Comment: Thank you, I found what was wrong. I should have done the drawing of my subviews in the viewDidLayoutSubviews function instead of viewDidLoad